# Sum of absolute values and the absolute value of the sum of these values?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, absolute-value

I'm working on a proof and I need some help with this:

I determined that for **some** situations ($x$ or $y$ are negative but not both):
$|x| + |y| > x + y$

How can I conclude using that statement the fact that:
$|x| + |y| > |x + y|$

Comment: Not in general, take one number negative for e.g.

Comment: I know that, but I need to make a general proof. So basically I'm trying to figure out a way to get to that conclusion without using specific examples.

Comment: Which definition are you using for $|x|$?

Comment: The fact that |x| = -x when x is negative

Comment: ...and $|x|=x$ for non-negatives.  Then you have four cases: non-negative+non-negative, non-negative+negative, negative+negative, and negative+non-negative.  Take them apart and it cover all possible cases.

Comment: Yeah I know. This question is about one of the specific cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try considering $|a+b|^2$, then using the property that $x^2 \geq 0$ for all x, you can obtain the desired inequality. Also your conclusion should be $|x|+|y| \geq |x+y|$. Notice that the inequality is *not* strict. (For example, if $x=y=0$ then certainly 
$|0|+|0| > |0+0|$ is false.) Another way is to use the fact that $-|a| \leq a \leq |a|$ for all numbers a (doing this for both $a$ and $b$, and then manipulating the inequalities, we can achieve what you want), however, this second route assumes that you at least are a little bit familiar with the rules of inequalities, particularly the rules regarding inequalities with absolute values.

As an example of how we would apply the squaring technique, we can do the following:
$$ 0 \leq |a+b|^2  = (a+b)(a+b)  = a^2 +2ab +b^2.$$
Now since $a^2 \geq 0$ is *always true* we can say that
$$a^2 +2ab +b^2 = |a|^2 +2ab +|b|^2.$$ Now we want to try to "force" an inequality. That is, we will replace $2ab$ with  $2|a||b|$. If $a$ and $b$ are both greater that $0$ then nothing would change, however, if they are not both greater than $0$ we would get the following:
$$
|a|^2 +2ab +|b|^2 \leq |a|^2 +2|a||b| +|b|^2
$$ notice that we have broken the chain of equal signs and forced an inequality. (There are still some more steps to do for you. Hint: What is $(|a|+|b|)^2$?)

Comment: Oh my inequality has a precondition: x < 0 ∧ y ≥ 0, so there isn't really a problem about that.

And how do I use that condition? I have the fact that |x| + |y| > x + y, where do I apply the square?

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that, $|a| < b \Rightarrow -b < a <b$? If you are allowed to use this property you can show that $x+y > -(|x|+|y|)$; then you are done. Also as far as "applying the square" goes, we do not exactly apply it like we would in normal mathematics. We start with $|a+b|^2$ the "chain" inequalities to get what we want. I will do the first few steps in my answer.

Comment: I can't use that property :( I need another approach. Any hints?

Comment: See my updated answer. Also as was mentioned earlier, you can try a proof by cases (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_exhaustion) however that may take a bit longer.

Answer (score 0):

**First method:**

Since $$|x+y|^2=(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2+2xy \leq x^2+y^2+2|x| |y|=(|x|+|y|)^2$$ we have $$|x+y| \leq |x| + |y| $$ which is equality if and only if : $$xy=|x||y|=|xy|$$ if and only if $x$ and $y$  ar both negatives or both positives. This means taht if $x$ and $y$ hav'nt the same sign we have:
$$|x+y| < |x| + |y|$$
But $x+y \leq |x+y|$  gives also $x+y < |x|+|y|$

**Second method:**

We have $$(|x|+|y|)-(x+y)=(|x|-x)+(|y|-y)$$
for all real number $a$ we have  $|a|-a \geq 0$, and equality holds if and only if $a$ is positive. Since $x$ or $y$ is'nt positive one of the numbers $|x|-x$ or $|y|-y$  is $ >0 $ so $|x|+|y| > x+y$