# Verify that $\lVert\cdot\rVert_1$ is a vector norm <triangular inequality>

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, vectors, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

We are given the 1-norm
$$\|x\|_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|.$$
 We want to show it is a vector norm. It has to satisfy properties

I solved them all except for the last one!

$$\|x+y\|_1 \le \|x\|_1+\|y\|_1$$

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the inequality $|x+y| < |x| + |y|$.

For the proof of the hint visit [Sum of absolute values and the absolute value of the sum of these values?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555053/sum-of-absolute-values-and-the-absolute-value-of-the-sum-of-these-values)